# Histogram with D3 , bars are not fitting hight of svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, histogram

am plotting histogram based on Data ( which is changing dynamically ) , but the height of some bars are not fitting the svg zone ( the exceed the svg area )
this is piece of code which i have doubt on :

```
private drawBars(data: any[]): void {
    let f = Math.min.apply(Math, this.fixedData.map(function (o) {
        return o.xAxis;
    }));
    /** Create the X-axis band scale */
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([f, 240])
        .domain(data.map(d => d.xAxis))
        .padding(0);

    /** Create the Y-axis band scale */
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, this.axisMax])
        .range([this.height, 0])
        .nice();


    /** Create and fill the bars */
    this.svg.selectAll("*").remove()
    this.svg.selectAll("bars")
        .data(data, d => d)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))
        .attr("fill", (d) => this.colorPicker(d))
}
```

and here is a proof of that weird behaviour :

[image]

any ideas and i would be thankful !

Comment: note that it is same beahiour for multiple data

Comment: It looks like `this.axisMax` is way too low. Can you check that the value is calculated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `this.axisMax` being set way too low, here:

```
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, this.axisMax])
        .range([this.height, 0])
        .nice();
```

You need to recalculate it based on the available data.

The domain of a scale holds the range of possible values it accepts, but, at least for `scaleLinear`, `scaleTime`, and some others, being outside that range doesn't throw an error or even return `NaN`. For these types of scales, the domain is instead used to identify a linear transformation between the input values and output pixels.

**For example**

Suppose you have a linear scale with domain [0, 10] and range [0, 100]. Then, `x = 0` gives pixel value `0`, and `x = 10` gives `100`. However, `x = 20` gives pixel value `200`, which is more than the given range.

Comment: thank you for answear , 
so the domain , and especially for axisMax can i dynmacially asign a value to always fit a radom range and given domain ?

Comment: Yes, whenever the data changes (is loaded from the server for example), update the domain. Many people only set the range once, when they define the size of the chart

Comment: yes i see , but this.axisMax is changed whenever the data is changed , which is the max of yAxis from object array of (x,y) values . for example for the image above , i get axisMax Value as 428 which is so lower to 1000 ( which is set manually to test it ) is tha logic ?

Comment: I don't understand. Is 428 too low and is it giving you the problem?

Comment: Then probably that calculation is wrong. Is it a stacked bar chart? Then you need to have the max of the sums of the bars. Or there is something else going on. Please share your code, this is just guessing

Comment: if (this.axisMax === -Infinity) {
            maxDomain = 1000;
        } else {
            maxDomain = this.axisMax * 3
        }
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, maxDomain])
            //.domain([0, this.sumAxis ])
            .range([this.height, 0])
            .nice();

Comment: That is weird code, I don't understand why you would use `axisMax` and `maxDomain` like that... If `axisMax` is wrong, or if `this.height` is wrong, this will give the wrong scale